# SSL: certificate signature failure

Tags: openssl, certificates, https

The situation is:

- there is a root certificate (a „home brew”)
- there is an „intermediary” certificate signed by the previous one (also a „home brew”)
- there are two hosts (*A* and *B*) on which the above (CA) certificates have been installed in

  ```
  /etc/ssl/certs/
  ```
- on host A a certificate *C1* (signed by the intermediary CA) and private key *K1* are configured to be used by a network (SOAP) listener.
- on host B a certificate *C2* (signed by the intermediary CA) and private key *K2* are configured to be used by a network (SOAP) listener.

On host *A* I can successfully use the network services from both hosts and issuing the commands on host *A*:

```
openssl s_client -connect A:18080
openssl s_client -connect B:18080
```

both return

```
...
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
...
```

However on host *B* I can't successfully use any of the network services (certificates are not validated) and issuing the commands on host *B*:

```
openssl s_client -connect A:18080
openssl s_client -connect B:18080
```

both return

```
...
Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
...
```

When the verification succeeds, the output from the above commands contains:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = CX, ST = SX, L = Loc, O = Org, emailAddress = user@org.cx
verify return:1
depth=1 C = CX, ST = SX, L = Loc, O = Org, emailAddress = user@org.cx
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CX, ST = Loc, L = Loc, O = Comp, OU = OX, CN = a.comp.int, emailAddress = user@comp.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=CX/ST=Loc/L=Loc/O=Comp/OU=OX/CN=a.comp.int/emailAddress=user@comp.com
   i:/C=CX/ST=SX/L=Loc/O=Org/emailAddress=user@org.cx
---
```

When the verification fails, the output from the above commands contains:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = CX, ST = SX, L = Loc, O = Org, emailAddress = user@org.cx
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CX, ST = Loc, L = Loc, O = Comp, OU = OX, CN = a.comp.int, emailAddress = user@comp.com
verify error:num=7:certificate signature failure
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CX, ST = Loc, L = Loc, O = Comp, OU = OX, CN = a.comp.int, emailAddress = user@comp.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=CX/ST=Loc/L=Loc/O=Comp/OU=OX/CN=a.comp.int/emailAddress=user@comp.com
   i:/C=CX/ST=SX/L=Loc/O=Org/emailAddress=user@org.cx
---
```

Can someone help me find out where the fault lies?

Is it that on host *B* (the one that cannot validate ether certificates) the certification chain (Root CA - Intermediary CA) is somehow „broken”?
What should I do to debug this further?

Even though openssl on host *B* cannot validate the certificates from ether hosts, Firefox running on host *B* also successfully validates those - of course using its own certificate store where the root CA and the intermediary CA mentioned above have been imported.

Again, from the side of host *A* everything works just fine, as expected.

One more thing: the command

```
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/CA.pem -untrusted /etc/ssl/certs/Int_CA.pem /home/<user>/.ssh/id_b.pub
```

on host *B* produces the result:

```
/home/<user>/.ssh/id_b.pub: OK
```

So this time everything seems to be in order.